# Automate the og:title and og:description tags with PHP

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph

I have unsuccessfully tried to automate the og:title and og:description tags for most of the day. I have a global.php file that contains some common meta tags that i want to be on all my pages. But the Title tag is not included, i do it on per-page basis. I do the same with the meta description tag. So the plan was to add og:title and og:description inside the global file and use some PHP magic to autopopulate these and be the same as the `<title>` and `<meta name="description"`

First, i've read for 2 hours trying to implement the title one, with suggestion from another article here.
I have this line working for many months getting my current URL (i use it for "copy link to this page" button)

```
$url =  'https://'."{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
$escaped_url = htmlspecialchars( $url, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
```

So i tried doing the title automation this way:

```
$html = file_get_contents($escaped_url);
$title = preg_match("/<title>([^<]*)<\/title>/im", $html, $matches);
```

and then `<meta property="og:title" content="<?=$title;?>">`

but this destroys my web server. Hangs indefinitely.

Even my simpler and cleaner solution for doing the Description tag also hangs my server.

```
$tags = get_meta_tags($escaped_url);
$description = $tags['description'];
<meta property="og:description" content="<?=$description;?>">
```

Do you guys have any ideas on how to automate this or should i just drop it and do it manually on every page?

Comment: You're creating an infinite loop of requests. What you're doing is requesting your own webserver to find out the title, that request will create another request to your own webserver and so on.

Comment: I would suggest that you have a look at how your webserver is generating your titles and copy that logic.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed your server is hanging,  since the program you call calls itself to gather the title. This is not the best approach.

I think you should add in your global.php the desired markup with template like value, for example :

```
<og:title value="{copy_meta_title}" />
```

Then in all your pages, you can replace the value with the actual one.

You can make use of ob_start and ob_get_clean, which can help you modify content before it is sent to the browser.

```
<?php //page.php

ob_start();
include('global.php');
$actual_title = "actual_title";
echo "<title>$actual_title</title>"
$head = ob_get_clean();
$head = str_replace('{copy_meta_title}',$actual_title,$head);
echo $head;
?>
```

The code may have errors sins it is written on the fly :)

Comment: That's interesting. How do i make this work - <og:title value="{copy_meta_title}" />

Comment: look at the provided code, just do str_replace on the content gathered from ob_get_clean, wich contains all the outputted content of global.php

Comment: If the variable is global you could use that instead of {copy_meta_title}.